# How to summarize counts as a percentage rather than absolute values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am currently working on  a project for an R class in which I am basically trying to answer a question using the Behavioral Risk Factor Surveillance System (BRFSS) 2013 data.
My goal is to make a grouped bar plot in order to be able to compare counts of a variable inside two different groups. To that end, I wrote the code:

```
brfss2013 %>%
  group_by(veteran3, sleepmore) %>%
  filter(!is.na(veteran3)) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=veteran3, y=count, fill=sleepmore)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

This returns me the following barplot:

[image: Barplot generated by the code]

How can I turn the counts into percentages inside the veteran3 "Yes" and "No" groups?

Comment: Please include the creation of `brfss2013` into your code.

Comment: @MartinGal how should I do that? I am quite unexperienced, I'm not sure what you mean by "creation". If I got it right, this is the link to the database codebook:  https://www.cdc.gov/brfss/annual_data/2013/pdf/CODEBOOK13_LLCP.pdf

Comment: In your summarize command, do not just count the n, but also calculate the proportion, i.e. count/sum(count). Maybe that‘s already what you want. If you want to show percentages with the % sign, please check the „scales“ package.

Comment: @deschen The problem is my summarise gives me a table with 2 rows for "veteran3 == "Yes" and 2 rows for "veteran3 == "No". Do you know how I could sum the counts exclusively for each of these groups? sum(count) returns me the total sum of all counts, including "No" and "Yes" veteran3.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fill position.

```
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="fill")
```